# Type 'Int' has no subscript members?

Tags: swift

I am coding my first application in Swift. Right off the bat I am sorry if this is a duplicate as I have looked at others errors and wasn't really sure how to insert the help they got into my code.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return textView.text.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let myText = Int(entertextTextView.text!)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(myText?[myText.index(myText.startIndex, offsetBy: indexPath.row)])"
        return cell
    }
```

I get a "Type 'Int' has no subscript members" error. I am trying to add a new cell into a textview for each character in a textview.

Comment: MyText = Int(..) it should be string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are adding a character to every cell, you shouldn't need to convert it to a `Int`. Only when it is a string will you be able to access a character using indices.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let myText = entertextTextView.text!
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(myText[myText.index(myText.startIndex, offsetBy: indexPath.row)])"
    return cell
}
```

Also, it doesn't matter if your content is a number or not, which is why i'm assuming you changed it to an `Int`. Unless you are performing arithmetic operations or similar operations on the number, you can just let the content be a `String`.